# How do I add a submenu to an existing menu in Magento?

Tags: magento

My existing code creates a menu that looks like this.

[image: custom magento menu]

But I want a menu that is a sub-menu of the Catalog menu.

Here is my existing code in `adminhtml.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <mycustom_menu translate="title" module="brands">
            <title>My Custom Menu Item</title>
            <sort_order>300</sort_order>
            <children>
                <!-- child items go here -->
                <subitem translate="title" module="brands">
                    <title>Manage Brands</title>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/mycustom_controller/</action>
                </subitem>
            </children>
        </mycustom_menu>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <mycustom_menu translate="title" module="brands">
                        <title>My Custom Menu Item</title>
                        <sort_order>300</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <subitem translate="title" module="brands">
                                <title>Subitem</title>
                                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            </subitem>
                        </children>
                    </mycustom_menu>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Instead of using `<mycustom_menu>` you need to re-use the nodename that was used in the `adminhtml.xml`  of the catalog module. That name is `catalog`.

So your XML should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <catalog>
            <children>
                <your_subitem>
                    <title>Subitem 1</title>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/your_action</action>
                </your_subitem>
            </children>
        </catalog>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <catalog>
                        <title>Subitem 1</title>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    </catalog>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Comment: When i try to add this code in the config.xml , the default catalog name was replaced with subitem in the acl roles. how can i correct it.

Comment: @Naveenbos you are right, code for the ACL is not correct, should be ` <acl>
  <resources>
   <admin>
    <children>
     <catalog>
                  <children>                
                   <your_subitem>
                       <title>Subitem 1</title>
                       <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                   </your_subitem>
                  </children>
     </catalog>
    </children>
   </admin>
  </resources>
 </acl>`

Answer (score 0):

For example to add submenu in customer tab:

```
<menu>
    <customer>
        <children>
          <vendor module="yourmodule">
            <title>Your Title</title>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            <action>admin_yourmodule/adminhtml_yourmoduleaction</action>
          </vendor>
        </children>
    </customer>
</menu>
```